# telnet not working though server and client are on

Tags: windows, telnet, netstat

i use a pc with windows 7.i tried to telnet to another host but it didn't work even though the host had enabled telnet server and i had enabled the client.So, i enabled telnet server on my pc and telnet to my pc. But this too failed with the error

```
Connecting To 172.17.4.155...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
Connect failed
```

Then i checked the tcpdump with ubuntu on a virtual machine. The dump said that connection closed with a reset flag sent. So, i checked if there was telnet server listening on port 23, using '**netstat -a**' on windows. There was no server listening on port 23. This is weird because in control panel's **Programs and Features** it says that client and server both are runnning.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: i even made a rule to allow inbound connections and outbound connections from telnet server through firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you sir for the help....But the problem was something else...What really was happening that though the telnet server was installed, it was off in the services i.e. it was disabled...Open the services using task manager and there click on services tab...then go to telnet and change its type to manual and start the service

Answer (score 3):

Click Start, and then click Control Panel.

On the Control Panel Home page, click Programs.

Under the section titled Programs and Features, click Turn Windows features on or off.

If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

In the Windows Features list, select Telnet Server, and then click OK.

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com